# I want to make a line movement when hovering to an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, gradient

I want to create a background gradient line that moves from down to up, back and forth when hovered inside an element, which means its separate.

What is the best way to do this? I've thought about making it hidden or none when not hovered and then making it appear and move when hovering but the problem is that it will mess up the height space in a navbar when it moves.

Comment: `background` gradient line will not interfere with height. You need to show us some sample of what you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this

html

```
<a href="#" class="elem">Hover me</a>
```

css

```
.elem{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.elem:before{
    content: "";
    width: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0px;
    background:linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out .5s; /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:all ease-in-out .5s; /* Safari */
    transition:all ease-in-out .5s;
}
.elem:hover:before{
    height: 100%;
}
```